# When convergence in distribution for $X$ and $Y$ implies for $X+Y$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X_n\rightarrow_L X$ and $Y_m\rightarrow_L Y$. We usually cannot assume that 
$X_n+Y_m\rightarrow_L X+Y$, since $X_m=^dN(0,1)$, and $Y_m=-X_m$, $X_m+Y_m\rightarrow 0$. So, when can be sure that it's true? From the example, I think it would be necessary for the the sequences to be independent. What more?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, if each $(X_n,Y_n)$ is independent *and if $(X,Y)$ is independent* then $(X_n,Y_n)\to(X,Y)$ in distribution and in particular, $X_n+Y_n\to X+Y$ in distribution. Is this your question?

Comment: @Did Yes, that's my question. Thanks ;)